# UICollectionViewCell scrambled position when re-entering screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, cell, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` which should show thumbnails of photos received from a server, much like the Photo app in iOS.

When the cells disappear from the view and then re-appear, their positions are reversed up until the point the finger releases the screen.

As soon as the finger releases the screen, the cells get properly re-positioned as well.

I can't figure out why iOS does this.

In the following GIF you'll see the cells, and a label inside indicating their index in their section.

As you can see, the index changes as I explained above.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Btw ignore the sixth image, I was just drinking soup.

**EDIT:** I noticed a pattern when the line of cells re-enter the screen.
This pattern is not visible in the image above, so I'll just have to explain it in text.
Ok, so at start as you can see the index of the images are increasing, from 0 to 4, right?
As I hold the finger down and scroll the line of cells in and out of view
the cell indexes change to 3, 1, 4, 2, 0.
followed by the second re-entering which changes their
indexes to 2, 1, 0, 4, 3.
On the third re-entering they change to 4, 1, 3, 0, 2.
And finally on the fourth re-entering they change back 
to original indexes 0,1,2,3,4.

This happens as long as I scroll the first line of cells in and out of view.

This is super-weird and makes no sense at all to me.

**EDIT 2:**
Ok, so it seems that the re-ordering of the cells to their correct index occurs only when the their images are changed/re-applied.

I added a variable which indicates if they've already been cached which I call `bool TNCached`, and upon `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I call a method from within the cell which is called `requestTN`, which in turn downloads the thumbnail of that specific cell from the server.

When the app fully receives the thumbnail, it sets the variable `TNCached` to `TRUE`, so next time the cell re-enters the view it won't re-download the thumbnail, thus not updating the cell, which causes the weird re-ordering of the cells indexes to persist even after I release my finger from the screen.

**Edit 3:**
Yaaay fixed it!

Turns out that the re-use of my UICollectionView cells is the "problem".
Not really a problem, but whenever a cell is reused, the UICollectionView reuses random cells of any given cell of the ones that disappeared when scrolled outside the screen.

So my question now is if the efficiency of my re-use of cells is maybe not that efficient?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your cells are being re-used,
which means that any of the cells that have disappeared from the screen can be used again, in any order.

What you need to do at `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is to setup your cell again.

By "setup" I mean to take the information from the data-source and apply it to your cell again.

So if cell 0 re-appears at NSIndexPath section 0 and item 4, then you simply go to your datasource and read the data that should be presented at NSIndexPath section 0 and item 4.